# How can i make a chat on Android Application?

Tags: android, chat

Well, i need to build an application with Android where im gonna need to build a chat too.
In that chat im gonna have some "rooms" and the users will be able to talk which other in that room.
I have a server in php where i can keep my sockets and that stuff... By the way i've never done it before so i've searched for some tutorial or some informations about how to build it and how to communicate my android application with the server and how to send message to all the users connected...
I've also though about making an application that request for database for new messages every 15 seconds, for example. But i know that its a not good way to to that...
Someone knows some website where show how to do tha chat clearly, or know some API that can help me with that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4543943/940096 and also [this](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+chat+application+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)

Comment: there shows how to do it with bluetooth...

Answer (score 1):

[MQTT](http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599) is a popular alternative to XMPP for chat on Android and also what Facebook uses for their chat application.